# Does URLSession persist cookies?

Tags: ios, swift

If the app makes a request that returns a response with a Set-Cookie header, 
the next time when I open the app and make the same request, will it attach the cookie from previous call?

```swift
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    })
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use default or background `URLSessionConfiguration` then cookies will be persisted.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411599-httpcookiestorage